# Upload picture from computer and send it to graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

i am trying to upload the picture from computer ,using a basic html input form,i have an array of global variable $_FILE with me.Now my question is how will i pass that picture to facebook graph api,do i need to store that picture on my server.How will i generate the link (path) of image stored(either temporary or permanent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `<?php echo $file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>` to find the server path and process it.